# Silex Help. Could anyone explain why I'm getting a 404 error here?

Tags: php, url, routes, phpstorm, silex

I am making a `Silex` application which takes a random image from a database and then displays it on the webpage. But I keep getting a `404 error` when trying to display the image. Here's my routeing code.

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\{Request, Response};

$app->get('/{width}/{height}', function (Request $request, Silex\Application $app, $width, $height){

    $image = $app['db']->fetchAssoc("SELECT filename FROM images ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");

    $placeholder = $app['image']
        ->make(__DIR__.'/../public/img/' .$image['filename'])
    ->fit($width, $height)
    ->greyscale()
    ->response('png');


    return new Response($placeholder, 200,[
        'Content-Type' => 'image/png'
    ]);


})->assert('width', '[0-9]+')->assert('height', '[0-9]+ ');
```

Because I have a route written has width and height I need to put a width and a height after my url do I do not get these errors.

[Errors page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HetEN.png)

But then once I do add the height lets say, 400 and 400, I get a 404 error page

[404 Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtequ.png)

Could anyone provide help?

Comment: You don't give an example of a URL that is 404ing - kinda relevant given the question - but this seems wrong: `assert('height', '[0-9]+ ')`. You have a trailing space in that pattern.

Comment: The error is stating that you don't have a router for the "GET /" request. So you are requesting your root document (```http://what.ever.com/```) which translates to "/" route. So you need to add a call to ```$app->get("/", function(...) { ...});```

Comment: What FULL URLs do you see in the browser's address bar when you see response on first and second screenshots? Right now it looks like you might be using PhpStorm's own built-in simple web server ... which is not really suitable to be used for serving sites with such dynamic URLs. If so -- on first screenshot request comes through to your Silex app and since you have no route for `/` it generates that error. On 2nd request the URL may simply not getting able to pass the webserver's initial routing logic ... so it never reaches your Silex app. Better use proper Apache/nginx for serving web pages

Comment: Do you have URL rewriting enabled?

Comment: Ahhh sorry guys for not including the URL that was pretty stupid of me, but I will update the images with the urls now.. The 400/400 at the end of the url is the dimensions of both the height and the width of the image.

Comment: Can you try ```http://localhost/index.php/400/400```? It seems you're not loading the rewrite to avoid the ```index.php``` URL part

Answer (score 0):

Since yours 404 is from nginx and not from silex I'd assume you've forgot to enable url-rewrites on your web-server (in your case it's nginx)

I also see, that this snippet is from https://www.codecourse.com/lessons/build-a-placekitten-clone

The Author shows how to enable rewrites at 03:36 (https://www.codecourse.com/lessons/build-a-placekitten-clone/1482)
but only for Apache Web-Server, not for nginx

See https://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/web_servers.html#nginx for more details how to configure your nginx

**UPDATE:**

I think you could test your image-generator and see it working at `/index.php/400/400` but for cleaner URLs you'll need rewrites